# MySQL - show field value only in first instance of each grouped value?

Tags: sql, mysql, dataset, group-by, grouping

I don't think this is possible, but I would like to be proved otherwise.

I have written a simple report viewing class to output the results of various database queries. For the purpose of improving the display, when I have a report with grouped data, I would like to display the field value only on the first row of each unique value - and I would like to do this at the query level, or it would necessitate additional logic in my class to determine these special values.

It will probably help to illustrate my requirements with a simple example. Imagine this dataset:

```
Year    Quarter    Total
2008    Q1         20
2008    Q2         25
2008    Q3         35
2008    Q4         40
2009    Q1         15
2009    Q2         20
2009    Q3         30
2009    Q4         35
```

If possible, I would like the dataset returned as:

```
Year    Quarter    Total
2008    Q1         20
        Q2         25
        Q3         35
        Q4         40
2009    Q1         15
        Q2         20
        Q3         30
        Q4         35
```

Is there any way of doing this progammatically in MySQL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN @r = year THEN NULL ELSE year END AS year,
        quarter,
        total,
        @r := year
FROM    (
        SELECT  @r := 0
        ) vars,
        mytable
ORDER BY
        year
```

`@r` here is a session variable. You can use these in `MySQL` like any variable in any procedural language.

First, it's initialized to zero inside the subquery.

Second, it's checked in the `SELECT` clause. If the current value of `@r` is not equal to `year`, then the `year` is output, else `NULL` is output.

Third, it's updated with current value of `year`.

Comment: +1 though this is something better done in the report client:P

Comment: +1 for a working solution, but one that requires considerable effort to maintain - more so than handling the functionality in my class. I think what I will do is append a value to the column name, to flag my class to display the data in a certain way. For instance, 'Year__FirstGroup'.

Comment: @BrynJ: as @Andomar says, this is of course better done on the client, but I dodn't really understand what do you mean by "effort to maintain". This query will not break being once written, there is nothing to maintain here :)

Comment: @Quassnoi - perhaps I should have said effort to produce, it's just I'll have a lot of reports to write over the next few weeks.

Comment: @BrynJ: ahh, OK. Session variable, though, are not that hard as soon as you get accustomed to them.

Comment: @Quassnoi - actually, I'm not entirely sure I understand the syntax on display...would you care to explain the logic? :-)

Comment: @Quassnoi - thanks for the explanation, makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you want to do this? What about existing records where the Year column is empty or null?

Beautifying the output belongs inside the report logic. In pseudocode it would be sth. like:

```
var lastYear = 0
foreach (record in records)
{
   if (record.Year == lastYear)
   {
     print "   "
   }
   else
   {
     print record.Year
     lastYear = record.Year
   }

   // print the other columns
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I understand what you're saying - I'm just looking for the easiest method to implement / maintain. If there were such a solution in MySql, perhaps in the form of a function such as GROUP_CONCAT etc, then that would be an easy, maintainable solution.

Comment: I think what I will do is append a certain string to the column names (at the query level) that I want grouped like this. For instance: SELECT YEAR(date) AS 'Year__FirstGroup', MONTH(date) AS Month, SUM(whatever) AS Total FROM mytable GROUP BY Year, Month

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you asked for, but...

Sounds like an iffy thing to be doing in MySQL in the first place. Just looking at the raw rows of data, 2008 and 2009's Q2s don't seem to make much sense as data rows. The issue is presentational, not a matter of fetching data. Sounds more like something to be written into your viewing class - when passed a certain parameter, for example, it will know not to repeat things like "2008".

This allows for greater reusability of code, as well: rather than rewriting the query when you want to present the data differently, say by quarters rather than be year, you can just change one of the arguments of the viewing class so that the same query with a different order clause can output:

```
Quarter   Year   Total
Q1        2008   20
          2009   15
Q2        2008   25
          2009   20
...
```

Comment: I appreciate that it does not make much sense from a data point of view - I was just hoping there would a simple way of doing this in mysql with a built-in function, in the same way you have GROUP_CONCAT etc.

Answer (score 1):

It does not exactly match your request but I would rather pivot my table. It allows to visually compare figures from the 2 years as you have one quarter per column:

```
SELECT Year, 
       SUM(IF(Quarter="Q1", Rev, 0)) AS Q1,
       SUM(IF(Quarter="Q2", Rev, 0)) AS Q2, 
       SUM(IF(Quarter="Q3", Rev, 0)) AS Q3, 
       SUM(IF(Quarter="Q4", Rev, 0)) AS Q4 
FROM t1 GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

You then have:

```
YEAR Q1   Q2   Q3   Q4
2008
2009
```